# RxJava2 - Necessity of onErrorResumeNext

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
fun remove(data: String): Single<JSONApiObject> {
    return service.remove(data)
            .onErrorResumeNext(ErrorHandler(ErrorParser()))
}
```

Is `onErrorResumeNext` necessary, if I don't intend to do anything `onError`? This is a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But it recommendable to implement the `onError` or `onErrorResumeNext` in order to handle whenever your subscription goes wrong. Otherwise, your program will crash.

For example, in your case, if your POST request fails you can make know your user that is caused by a network disconnection, fields missing or if the server is down.